# Youth team travel within the US: best way and tips to reduce cost?

Tags: usa, budget, group-travel

I am a youth hockey coach and have 16 skaters and additional parents that are looking to go to one or more out-of-state tournaments this season.  Does anyone have any recommendations for getting the best deal?  In the past we've left it to individual parents to book their own travel, but I'd rather travel as a group.

I'm looking into group airfare discounts as well as traveling by coach in order to make the journey a "team experience".

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Travelling how far out of state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [GroupTravel](http://grouptravel.org/).

You can get group rates for airfare and hotels. We use this website to get deals on hotels for our gymnastics team. Good luck.